# A characterization of bidiscrete spans

Tags: category-theory

The following definition

> **2.9.** An object $A$ of a bicategory $\mathscr{K}$ is said to be *bidiscrete*, when, for all objects $X$ of $\mathscr{K}$, the category $\mathscr{K}(X,A)$ is equivalent to a discrete category. This means precisely that, for all arrows $f, g : X \to A$, there is at most one 2-cell $f\Rightarrow g$, and, if there is one, it is invertible.  Write $\mathrm{D}\mathscr{K}$ for the category whose objects are the bidiscrete objects of $\mathscr{K}$ and whose arrows are isomorphism classes of arrows in $\mathscr{K}$ between such objects.
>
> **2.10.** A span $(p,E,q)$ from $B$ to $A$ in $\mathbf{Cat}$ is bidiscrete if and only if, for all arrows $\xi,\eta : e \to e'$ in $E$ such that $p\xi = q\eta$ and $p\xi$, $q\xi$ are invertible, it is the case that $\xi = \eta$ and $\xi$ is invertible. Objects of $\mathrm{Fil}(B,A)$, $\mathrm{Fir}(B,A)$, $\mathrm{Fib}(B,A)$ are bidiscrete if and only if they are bidiscrete as spans.

from

> Street, Ross. ["Conspectus of variable categories."](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(81)90021-9) Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra 21.3 (1981): 307-338.

blatantly contains a typo; I think it should be corrected as follows:

> for all arrows $\xi,\eta : e \to e'$ such that $p\xi = p\eta$, $q\xi = q\eta$, and $p\xi,q\xi$ invertible, it is the case that $\xi=\eta$ is invertible.

For context, span is defined as

> **1.12.** For object $U$, $V$ of $\mathscr{C}$, the bicategory $U\int V$ $($or rather, $U\int\mathscr{C}(-,V))$ is called the *bicategory of spans from $U$ to $V$* in $\mathscr{C}$. The objects $(v,S,u)$ are *spans* from $U$ to $V$ and the arrows diagrams
>   $$\require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}
> S @>u>\searrow\quad\qquad\Uparrow\ \omega> U \\
> @VvV\stackrel{\sigma}{\Rightarrow}\quad\quad\ \searrow\ w V @AAu'A \\
> V @<\qquad\qquad\searrow\ \ <v'< S'
> \end{CD}$$

where $U\int X$ is

> **1.2.** For each object $U$ of $\mathscr{C}$, the bicategory $U\int X$ is described as follows. An object is a triple $(x,S,u)$ where $u : S \to U$ is an arrow in $\mathscr{C}$ and $x$ is an object of $XS$. An arrow $(\xi,\omega,w):(x,S,u)\to(x',S',u')$ consists of arrows $w : S \to S'$, $\xi : x \to (Xw)x'$ in $\mathscr{C}$, XS, respectively, and a 2-cell $\omega : u'w \Rightarrow u$ in $\mathscr{C}$. A 2-cell $\rho : (\xi,\omega,w)\to(\xi_1,\omega_1,w_1)$ is a 2-cell $\rho : w \to w_1$ in $\mathscr{C}$ such that $\omega = \omega_1 \cdot u'\rho$ and $\xi_1 = (X\rho)x'\cdot\xi$. Composition of arrows in $U\int X$ is performed as in a Kleisli category for a monad[.]

I'm not able to prove that this is equivalent to being discrete, and in particular, assuming discreteness, I'm not able to prove that this property holds. Is the definition for this criterion wrong? How can it be corrected, and the statement proved?